# Evaluate or Show HTML using Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, rss

I have this...portion of code in Javascript:

```
 var description = document.createElement('P');

 description.className='rssBoxDescription';

 description.innerHTML = itemTokens[2];

 div.appendChild(description);
```

I see that description gets the HTML value and displays as plain HTML coding not as HTML processing it shouldbe ... how to convert this HTML value in description to be appended to div element shown as HTML...which is not showing.

Also it has value something like:

```
<table><tr><td style="padding: 0 5px"><ahref="xttp://picasaweb.google.com/linktoimagepage"><imgtag style="border:1px solid #5C7FB9" s_rc="xttp://lh3.ggpht.com/imagepath" alt="image.jpg"/></a></td><td valign="top"><font color="#6B6B6B">Date: </font><font color="#333333">Jun 28, 2007 9:00 AM</font><br/><font color=\"#6B6B6B\">Number of Comments on Photo:</font><font color=\"#333333\">0</font><br/><p><ahref="xttp://picasaweb.google.com/linktoimage"><font color="#3964C2">View Photo</font></a></p></td></tr></table>
```

Pls help
Anita

@SARFARAZ ... YES...I am using the script on dhtmlgoodies.com/scripts/rss-scroller/js/ajax.js

It worked as :
`description.replace(/&amp;lt;/g,"<");`
and
`description.replace(/&amp;gt;/g,">");`

Comment: is your div also created using createElement (div.appendChild(description))?

Answer (score 1):

It could be that the `>` and the `<` have been encoded like `&gt;` and `&lt;`

Try replacing `&gt;` with `>` and `&lt;` with `<` in `itemTokens` before assigning it as the DIV innerHTML and see if it works

Answer (score 0):

**[It seems to be working for me](http://jsbin.com/efela3/2)**. Try posting entire code including the div that is created dynamically.